# Building a trending algorithm based on post count and frequency

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Say I have a Board model. Boards have many Posts. I simply want to find the boards that have the highest post count within the span of (x) days. Below is my extremely naive approach to this. With the code provided I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "posts")
LINE 1: SELECT  "boards".* FROM "boards" WHERE (board.posts.created_...
                                                ^
: SELECT  "boards".* FROM "boards" WHERE (board.posts.created_at >= '2019-06-05 12:14:30.661233') LIMIT $1
```

---

Please let me know if there's a better way to do this in addition the error I'm receiving.

```
class Board < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts

  scope :trending, -> { includes(:posts).where('board.posts.created_at >= ?', Time.now-7.days).order(posts_count: :desc) }
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :board, counter_cache: true
end
```

**Update:**
So I managed to come up with a working scope but not 100% sure if it's the most optimal. Your thoughts would be appreciated:

```
scope :trending, -> { includes(:posts).where(posts: { created_at: Time.now - 7.days }).order(posts_count: :desc) }
```

Comment: just one change in your last updated query. by using counter cache you get all posts count not the latest ones

Comment: Ah yes. You're right! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

```
Board.joins(:posts)
     .select("boards.*, count(posts.id) as latest_posts_count")
     .where('posts.created_at >= ?', 7.days.ago)
     .order('latest_posts_count desc')
     .group('boards.id')
```

Try this, you will need to join it and group them by `board_id`

```
Board.joins(:posts)
     .select("boards.*, count(posts.id) as posts_count")
     .where('posts.created_at >= ?', 7.days.ago)
     .order('posts_count desc')
     .group('boards.id')
```

Explanation:

- We joined (inner join) the tables so by default you get only boards which has at least one post associated with it
- we ordered them based on posts count
- we grouped them based on boards.id

Comment: I get this error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  ORDER BY "posts_count" is ambiguous)
LINE 1: ...2:40:52.315019') GROUP BY posts.board_id ORDER BY posts_coun...`

Comment: ok, my bad you're already using counter cache. updating the solution

Comment: check the update, you can't use counter_cache column here. reason is you have all the associated posts count in posts_count

Comment: but you need the scope to work based on posts count in last 7 days

Comment: Hey. So with your updated query I get this error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "boards.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function)
LINE 1: SELECT  boards.*, count(posts.id) as latest_posts_count FROM`

Comment: change group by to `boards.id`

Comment: Perfect and thank you for the thorough explanation.